# Left inverse of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, inverse

Let $f$ be the function  $f\colon \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, defined by rule $f(n)=n^2$.

Needed to find two left inverse functions for $f$. I know only one: it's $g(n)=\sqrt{n}$. Does anyone can help me to find second left inverse function?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $2$ left inverse functions? I see only one inverse function here.

Comment: @Inceptio: I suppose this is why the exercise is somewhat tricky. One is obvious, but as my answer points out -- that obvious inverse is not well-defined.

Comment: @Ilya : What's a left inverse function?  A function $g$ with $g \circ f = $ identity?

Comment: see definition here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt n$ is not always an integer, so this is not the correct function, because its range is not the natural numbers.

**Hint:** You can round a non-integer up and down.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, define $f_{n}: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as 
\begin{eqnarray}
f_{n}(x)=\left \{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
\sqrt{x} & \text{ when }x\text{ is a perfect square }\\
x+n &otherwise
\end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
 Then $f_{n}~ o ~f (x)=f_{n}(x^2)=x$.

Each $f_{n}$ is a left inverse of $f$.